# What is the shortest code in Java which can be used check primes?

Tags: java, primes

I have been trying to come up with the shortest block of code in Java to check if a number is prime or not. This is what I came up with, which is 52 characters - excluding whitespaces.

```
for(int i = 2; i < n;)
if(n % i++ == 0) 
    return false;
return true;
```

Can anyone suggest anything shorter than this?

**NOTE** : You can assume that the method header `public boolean isPrime(int n){}` has been written for you, and `n` is the integer to be tested.

Comment: Why do you need it exactly? Is it a part of some competition or what?

Comment: What do you mean by shortest? Least byte code? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You can make it shorter by calling another method which does this already.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant. In programming, we are not always finding the shortest code (although sometimes the shorter the better), but the most efficient code, or a balance between the two. In the prime example, I would stop the loop at the square root of n. More code, but more efficient.

Comment: This question belongs on [CodeGolf.SE]. I'm pretty certain it's been asked there a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

Since performance and clarity don't appear to matter, you don't need to finish early

```
boolean b = 1>0;
for(int i = 2; i < n;)
    b &= n % i++ != 0;
return b;
```

`1>0` is shorter than `true` and `0>0` is shorter than `false`

Comment: By removing all new lines, spaces, the source code:
`for(int i=2;i<n;)if(n%i++==0)return 0>0;return 1>0;` is shorter than
`boolean b=1>0;for(int i=2;i<n;)b&=n%i++!=0;return b;` :p

Comment: And it is very good idea to use `0>0` instead of `false`, if we neglect the readability of the source code:).

Comment: I know it's been 3 years, and this question is also closed as off-topic as it belongs on the codegolfing stackexchange, but this is shorter: `for(int i=2;i<n;)n=n%i++<1?0:n;return n>1;` (Perhaps @Pawel also likes to know.)

Answer (score 2):

48, if you are allowed to use an existing API (and the import statement does not count):

```
return BigInteger.valueOf(n).isProbablePrime(9);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking for a big prime no's 
you can first check

```
if(n>=5){
    if(n%6==1||n%6==5){
        for(i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++){
            if(n%i==0)  
                return false
                else return true;
        }
    }
}
```

this will help remove many cases,as every prime no >= 5 is of the form 6K+1 or 6K-1

Answer (score 0):

If by shortest you imply faster code then you can iterate till sqrt(n) only, as no number will have factors greater than squareroot of the number itself

Comment: And you can skip all even numbers (except the first).